# How can I have design time support for my custom user controls in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, compact-framework, user-controls

I'm an creating a custom user control for .NET Compact Framework and I want to keep design time support.

I'd like to think in Visual Studio 2008 that this is not the crazy almost impossible task it once used to be.

And I'm hoping there is a simple tutorial somewhere that will show me, it is a snap.

Any chance?

Comment: +1 I will keep an eye on this one; wanted to ask about this myself today...

Comment: Hey Joel, You left a comment on my answer that you would give it a try. Did it work? I would love your feedback, and for the benifit of the rest of the users of this site please upvote or downvote replys to your questions and mark one as the answer if it has answered your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creating and Migrating Smart Device Custom Controls by Using Visual Studio 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446500.aspx)

I liked this one better, and it looks like VS 2008 works the same way as VS 2005. There is a download as well at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample you can download [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180794(VS.80).aspx) that shows how to incorporate a WYSIWYG design-time experience.

Also there is annother tutorial [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478960.aspx). Look at the section on the "Designer".

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try. It mentions, "The sample can be built for Pocket PC or Smartphone, using either version 1.0 or version 2.0 of the .NET Compact Framework." So it might be out of date, since we're on version 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008. But I'll find out. Either way thanks for the heads up.