# How can I hide the resizing handles of a control in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls, windows-forms-designer

I have an UserControl and would like to hide the resizing handles in design-time, just like the TextBoxControl, that has only two handles (left and right ones)... the height of the textbox is fixed, unless you say it is multiline. In that case, the textbox shows all nine resizing handles.

Comment: Are you talking about in the forms designer?  Or when the application is actually run by the user?

Comment: @AaronLS: Talking about design-time.

Comment: Context suggests it's a question about integration with the winforms designer, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to implement a custom designer ([ControlDesigner](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.aspx)) for your control and then override the `SelectionRules` property.

Useful reference:

[Extending Design-Time Support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37899azc.aspx)

Comment: I don't think `ControlDesigner` is supported in CF so you might be better checking [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923570/how-can-i-have-design-time-support-for-my-custom-user-controls-in-visual-studio).

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to draw your own control and define the size in the class.  I believe if you inherit a user control you'll always have the option to resize.