# Emulating TrackBar Resizing Behavior in a UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I'm currently implementing a double `TrackBar` with two sliders. Things are going well, but I'm not sure how to go about implementing the sizing properties a `TrackBar` has.

In the Winforms editor in Visual Studio, a `TrackBar` with `AutoSize` set to `true` automatically sizes vertically and only gives you handles to size it horizontally (with the default `Orientation` value):

[image: Trackbar Example]

However, I'm not sure how to get these sizing properties with my custom control:

[image: Custom Control]

Sizing it myself works fine for now, but I'd like to emulate `TrackBar`'s behavior. How would I go about that?

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2494865/how-can-i-hide-the-resizing-handles-of-a-control-in-windows-forms