# How to create a user container control in compact framework?

Tags: c#, winforms, compact-framework

When we need to create a container control in "regular" framework,
we simply add

```
using System.ComponentModel;
```

and an attribute to the control class:

```
[Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", 
           typeof(IDesigner))]
public partial class MyContainerControl : UserControl
....
```

However, in compact framework this seems to be impossible since the `DesignerAttributes` class does not exist.

I already have the user control, but I need it to act as a container in design time.
I've tried googling anything I could think of, but came up with nothing.
Is there any way to create a container user control except inheriting an existing container control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UserControl class inherits directly from ContainerControl which the same inheritance as Form. Oddly, Panel inherits from ScrollableControl (ContainerControls parent) so despite being a panel it isn't a Container.

Anyway, it's not the inheritance that's the issue. The design time control is actually defined in a separate assembly compiled with the full framework to give you the attributes back (hopefully sharing the source between the two). It's really a completely separate control.

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923570/how-can-i-have-design-time-support-for-my-custom-user-controls-in-visual-studio)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand how that answers my question. Sure, a user control inherits from ContainerControl, but if you don't specify the `Designer` attribute you can't drag and drop other controls on it at design time (and that's what I'm looking for in compact framework)

Comment: @ZoharPeled. That's the point in the second paragraph. You can't do it in the CF, you need to create a separate design time assembly which is built using the full framework.